# "java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the path specified)" error when run the maven project using command line

Tags: maven, filenotfoundexception

In the below code, I have used apache poi to read excel file. The code is working fine in Eclipse. But when I used maven commands to run the program, it displays below error.

[commands used in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zul1n.png)

```
package Question6;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadAnWriteDate { 
    
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        
        ArrayList<List> a=new ArrayList<List>();
        a=read_data ("src/main/resources/input_excel/StudentDetails.xlsx", "Sheet1"); 
        print_data(a);  
    }
    

    public static ArrayList<List> read_data(String workbookPath, String sheetName){
        
        ArrayList<List> testdata = new ArrayList<List>();
        
        try
        {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(workbookPath));
            
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName); 
            
            //FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            
            int rowCount=sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int columnCount=sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            
            
            for(int i=1; i<=rowCount; i++) {
                List <Object> rowData=new ArrayList<Object>();
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                
                for(int j=0; j<columnCount;j++) {
                    
                    XSSFCell cell=row.getCell(j);
                    switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                    case STRING:
                        rowData.add(cell);
                        break; 
                    case NUMERIC: 
                        rowData.add(cell);
                        break;                      
                    }
                }   

                testdata.add(rowData);
            }   
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return testdata;
        
    }
    
    
    
    public static void print_data(ArrayList<List> data)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<data.size(); i++) {
            List<Object> x = new ArrayList<>();
            x=data.get(i);
            
            for (int j=0;j<x.size(); j++){
                System.out.println(x.get(j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Folder stucture:
[folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsHZz.png)

error:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2lrb.png)

I have tried by added the excel fill in all the folders and in the coding by giving only file name also. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

Add your resource as:

```
 <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*/**</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

And change path to to relative so:
a=read_data ("input_excel/StudentDetails.xlsx", "Sheet1");
and should be fine

Don't forget to apply maven changes on change project pom.

Comment: Thanks Kamil.
But still getting same error.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: input_excel\StudentDetails.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
        at Question6.ReadAnWriteDate.read_data(ReadAnWriteDate.java:33)
        at Question6.ReadAnWriteDate.main(ReadAnWriteDate.java:21)

Comment: So you can try load  ("StudentDetails.xlsx", "Sheet1")